# iOS 360 endless rotation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewanimation

I've this code for endless rotating an `UIImageView`

```
            [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f
                                  delay:0.0f
                                options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear|UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat
                             animations: ^{
                                 self.spinner.transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -M_PI);
                             }
                             completion: ^(BOOL finished) {
                             }];
```

But the first I call this method the image, it rotate clockwise instead anti clockwise. If I re-call this method while image is rotating, it change direction and start rotate anti clockwise.

Ideas?

Comment: how r u calling this again ? where did u put this code ?

Comment: in a IBAction method on UIButton

Comment: do you want to rotate it in opposite direction after button click ? @Fry

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a `CABasicAnimation` instead since it is far more powerful. You have to call the below snippet only once and the animation will run indefinitely:

```
CABasicAnimation *rotate = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];
rotate.toValue = @(M_PI * 2); // use @(-M_PI * 2) for counter clockwise
rotate.duration = 0.3;
rotate.cumulative = true;
rotate.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
[self.spinner.layer addAnimation:rotate forKey:@"rotateAnim"];
```

Swift:

```
let rotate = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "transform.rotation.z")
rotate.toValue = M_PI * 2
rotate.duration = 0.3
rotate.cumulative = true
rotate.repeatCount = HUGE
self.spinner.layer.addAnimation(rotate, forKey: "rotateAnim")
```

Comment: what is the rotation.z for ? do z stand for z axis ?

Comment: @Mr.T yes, it is for z axis. Because it is a 3D-rotation and the z axis is the one axis coming out of the device towards you. rotating around that axis is exactly what you would want.

Comment: understood!! Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

> In iOS, a positive value specifies counterclockwise rotation and a
>   negative value specifies clockwise rotation.

```
  CGAffineTransformRotate(CGAffineTransformIdentity, -M_PI)
```

**Update:** M_PI is constant not effected by the negative value. Somehow -M_PI is still taken as positive at the end!!!

If you give -180 it will rotate in clockwise, and if you give 180 it will rotate anti-clockwise

Comment: I obtain the same effect. Even with a positive value, image rotates clockwise